# R/ Regex: Remove an immediate character in front of a pattern along with the pattern

Tags: r, regex

I have this string:

```
cd/etc/init[BKSP][BKSP]it.d[ENTER]
```

I want the end result to be like this :

```
cd/etc/init.d[ENTER]
```

It would remove all the `[BKSP]` substrings along with an immediate character in front of it.

I have this sub function:

```
sub(“(.?\\[BKSP\\]+)+”, “”, string, perl = TRUE)
```

But getting: `cd/etc/iniit.d[ENTER]` instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: So given the input `abcd[BKSP]e` would it yield `abcd` or `abce`?

Comment: Use `gsub("(?s).(?R)?\\[BKSP]", "", string, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew very nice, it should be posted as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
gsub("(?s).(?R)?\\[BKSP]", "", string, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1hw7WJ/1/)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - turns on the DOTALL modifier
- `.` - matches any char
- `(?R)?` - matches 1 or 0 ocurrences of the whole pattern (recurses the whole pattern)
- `\\[BKSP]` - a literal substring `[BKSP]`.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/t27ft0):

```
string <- c("cd/etc/init[BKSP][BKSP]it.d[ENTER]", "abcd[BKSP]e")
gsub("(?s).(?R)?\\[BKSP]", "", string, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "cd/etc/init.d[ENTER]" "abce"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
test <- "cd/etc/init[BKSP][BKSP]it.d[ENTER]"
pattern <- "\\[BKSP\\]\\w*"
gsub(pattern, "", test)
```

Which yields

```
[1] "cd/etc/init.d[ENTER]"
```

Comment: I think the OP means that if the input is `abcd[BKSP]e` the result would be `abce`, but this is an assumption and should be clarified by OP. `[BKSP] = backspace`